# Specify more product versions in single Bugzilla bug

Tags: version, bugzilla

Is it possible to specify more product versions in single Bugzilla bug?
That'd help the need to clone the same bug several times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing is probably to use Tracking Flags for the different versions to be track of affectance, fix state, …

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's very nicely described in https://blogs.gnome.org/aklapper/2013/08/02/bugzillatips-tracking-branches/